# Delete an array object is deleting reference also

Tags: javascript, arrays

In array map function i'm trying to copy an object and delete the copied resource object. But it's removing both of the objects.

```
let array = [{
  'data': '1'
}, {
  'data': '2'
}];

array.map((val) => {
  val.temp = val.data;
  delete val.data;
});
```

In this it's removing both objects

I want to remove data object in the array and add temp object,

final result should be

```
array = [{
  'temp': '1'
}, {
  'temp': '2'
}];
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Kohli, please try to clone the array object before deleting it. As per my understanding, Javascript objects are referred by reference. It acts on single object until unless you clone it.

Comment: map function calls the arrow function for all the elements in the array.

Comment: It looks working to me. What's the expected behavior to you?

Comment: It's working fine

Comment: Welcome to SO. As per all the comments it is unclear what you are expecting. Suggest you take a few minutes to read through [ask] then edit the question with  more absolute explanation of what you are hoping to accomplish and what expectations are. Note that `map()` returns a new array and you are also using it incorrectly if all you want to do is use it to loop over the existing array. `forEach()` is a more appropriate method for doing that

Comment: @jrhamza i tried cloning also still same issue is there

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're not `return`ing the updated `val` after modifying it like so:

```js
const array = [{'data': '1'}, {'data': '2'}];

const res = array.map((val) => {
  val.temp = val.data;
  delete val.data;
  return val; // required in the `.map()` callback to set the new value
});

console.log(res);
```

However, if all you wish to do is convert each object such that it's key is `tmp`, you can do this more elegantly using destructuring like so:

```js
const array = [{'data': '1'}, {'data': '2'}];

const res = array.map(({data:tmp, ...rest}) => ({tmp, ...rest}));
console.log(res);
```